# primefaces dataTable selection Object type

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "menuCtrl")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MenuControleur extends AbstractControleur implements Serializable {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationControleur.class);

private PanierBeans[] selectedRep;

public PanierBeans[] getSelectedRep() {
    return selectedRep;
}

public void setSelectedRep(PanierBeans[] selectedRep) {
    this.selectedRep = selectedRep;
}

// cache
private List<Spectacle> spectacles;
private List<Representation> representations;
private Spectacle specSelec = new Spectacle();


private List<Artiste> artistes;
private List<Representation> representationsFiltrees;
private List lignesSelec;

public List getLignesSelec() {
    return lignesSelec;
}

public void setLignesSelec(List lignesSelec) {
    this.lignesSelec = lignesSelec;
}
```

and in the facelet i have this table

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="rep" value="#{menuCtrl.specSelec.representations}" widgetVar="representationsTable"   
                     emptyMessage="Pas de représentation trouvée avec les criteres précisés" filteredValue="#{menuCtrl.representationsFiltrees}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                     style="background: none"      >  

            <f:facet name="header">  
                <p:outputPanel>  
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="representationsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
                </p:outputPanel>  
            </f:facet>  


            <p:column id="photoArtiste"  headerText="Artiste"  >  
                <ui:param name="imgPath" value="images:#{menuCtrl.specSelec.artiste.lienPhoto}.png" />
                <p:graphicImage value="#{resource[imgPath]}" />  
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="nomArtiste" filterBy="#{rep}"   
                      headerText="Artiste"  
                      filterMatchMode="contains">  
                <h:outputText value="#{menuCtrl.specSelec.artiste.nom}" />  
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="nomSpectacle" filterBy="#{rep}"   
                      headerText="Spectacle"  
                      filterMatchMode="contains">  
                <h:outputText value="#{menuCtrl.specSelec.nomSpectacle}" />  
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="addColumn" filterBy="#{rep.adresse}"  
                      headerText="Ville" footerText="contains"  
                      filterMatchMode="contains">  
                <h:outputText value="#{rep.salle.adresseSalle}" />  
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="dateDebutColumn"  headerText="Date" footerText="startsWith">

                <h:outputText value="#{rep.dateDebut}" 
                              id="popupDate"> 
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="d/M/yyyy" /> 
                </h:outputText>


            </p:column> 
            <p:column id="dispColumn"   
                      headerText="Disponibilité">  
                <p:inputText id="champDisBillets" value="100" size="5" readonly="true" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="qteBillets"   
                      headerText="Qte Billets">  
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{buttonBean.number}">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="4" itemValue="4" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="6" itemValue="6" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>   
            </p:column> 
            <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date2}" id="popupCal" /> 

            <p:column id="priceColumn" filterBy="#{rep}"   
                      headerText="Prix" footerText="contains"  
                      filterMatchMode="contains"> 

                <p:inputText id="prixBillets" value="#{rep.prix}" readonly="true" size="5"/>  
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

nom i want to add checkboxes but in that case i would have to add a selection attributes that point to one of the managed bean attributes, thing is the rows are populated with differents inds of objects so what type o object should in selection ?

Comment: I think you can make the different objects extend a superclass, use the superclass as the selected object, and then have some kind of case statement that checks if the object is an `instanceof` one of the subclasses. you can always just use `java.lang.Object` as the selected Object.